# Dynamically create and destroy a Three.js scene without leaking memory

Tags: javascript, memory, three.js, webgl, memory-leaks

Lets say we had a page with two buttons, create and destroy. When you click create the Three.js scene in this memory test below is dynamically added to the page and starts running. Clicking destroy should remove the scene, dealocate all buffers and free up all memory etc.
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_test_memory.html

Does anyone know how to do this without framing the scene and changing the url?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to using the dispose() method in side geometry, material and texture.

```
geometry.dispose();
material.dispose();
texture.dispose();
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_test_memory.html

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a garbage-collected language. If you no longer have any references to a certain object (like an old scene), then the memory will eventually be reclaimed, unless there is a bug in the implementation somewhere. The page you linked to seems to work fine, though.

Comment: Thanks Claudiu, but the memory isn't being released even if I remove all references.

I'm not sure if WebGL has different rules, bugs in the implementation or whatever. I have seen some bug reports that mention this but nothing too concrete

Comment: Could you put up a test page so I could take a look?

Comment: Although the 3d models are unloaded from the scene, they still exist in memory unless Garbage Collector removes them. See the following stackoverflow thread for currently available commands for calling GC in several browsers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227422/is-there-any-way-to-force-the-javascript-garbage-collector-in-webkit-based-brows

In Opera and Edge is easy to use js GC commands. For Chrome you must unlock the command first. For Firefox I have not found any straight-forward js command (Type "about:memory" -> "Minimize memory usage").

Answer (score 1):

I myself was troubled with this question for long, raised bug reports with chrome and Three.js but was not able to find any solution.

For some reasons memory does not free up even after a long time and seems something keeps pointing to memory block and hence garbage collector never free it up.

However here is what did the trick for me

1. Create an array which will hold all items added to scene.
2. Whenever you add an extra item to scene, add it to this array.
3. On destroy function, run scene.remove('item name') to remove them from scene.
4. Now iterate through array and manually make all the items undefined.

Following this way, I was able to claim more than 600MB of RAM from Three.js scene.

**update**

Answer by Mr. Doob and WestLangley [Memory leak with three.js and many shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945092/memory-leak-with-three-js-and-many-shapes?rq=1), I am yet to test this with my code.

In webGLRenderer, after removing a mesh with

`scene.remove( mesh )`,

you can deallocate the memory with

`renderer.deallocateObject( mesh );`

You can deallocate textures with

`renderer.deallocateTexture( texture );`

Comment: does this work in r69? i think rendere no londeg have those methods ?

Comment: Not sure about current updates, have not worked on it since r62.